# Python - How do I get my program to ask for an input repeatedly but still store the other inputs?

Tags: python, input, store, repeat

Basically, my program needs to be able to store recipes. I have to ask the user to input an ingredient along with the quantity and unit. I'm sorry if this is somewhat vague, but how can I program it so that I can ask the user to input multiple ingredients until they've entered the number of ingredients that they need to enter? Thank you very much.

```
#Ask the user to input ingredient name, quantity and measurement

ingredient = input("Name is your ingredient: ")
ingredientquantity = int(input("What is the quantity of this ingredient: "))
ingredientunit = input("What is the unit of your ingredient: ")
```

^^^ This is what I've written so far, but how could this be repeated and **STILL STORE** any previous entries?

Answer (score 4):

Write a loop, and store them in a list. A while loop might be prudent here

```
ingredients = []
while True:
    name = raw_input("Name is your ingredient: ")
    quantity = int(raw_input("What is the quantity of this ingredient: "))
    unit = raw_input("What is the unit of your ingredient: ")
    ingredients.append((name, quantity, unit))

    cont = raw_input("Continue adding ingredients? [y/n]")
    if not cont.lower() in ("y", "yes"):
        break
```

The code will ask for the stuff you wanted, and append these as a three tuple to a list after each iteration. Now once you're done (by answering anything but a y or yes), you'll have a list of three tuples `(ingredient name, ingredient quantity, ingredient unit)`.

Have a look at the [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html) part in the official documentation.

Demo:

```
Name is your ingredient: Flour
What is the quantity of this ingredient: 7
What is the unit of your ingredient: dl
Continue adding ingredients? [y/n]y
Name is your ingredient: Butter
What is the quantity of this ingredient: 50
What is the unit of your ingredient: gr
Continue adding ingredients? [y/n]y
Name is your ingredient: Sugar
What is the quantity of this ingredient: 1
What is the unit of your ingredient: dl
Continue adding ingredients? [y/n]n

>>> print ingredients
[('Flour', 7, 'dl'), ('Butter', 50, 'gr'), ('Sugar', 1, 'dl')]
```

EDIT: Changed the `input` calls to `raw_input` because in python 2.7, `input` attempts to convert the input to whatever it thinks the input is. Thus numbers become integers and so forth. Not necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
def validated_input(prompt,input_type=str):
    while True:
       try:
            return input_type(raw_input(prompt))
       except:
            print "Error Invalid Input, Try Again"

def get_ingredient():
    return validated_input("Ingredient Name:",str),validated_input("Qty:",int),validated_input("Units:",str)


ingredients = [get_ingredient() for _ in range(validated_input("Enter Number Of Ingredients:",int))]
```

Comment: I feel this is the more pythonic answer, but why not using raw_input instead of input, so in python 2.7 the user does not have to quote the strings?

Comment: Oh I was just copying OP ... i was unaware of his version :) ...changing to raw_input (of coarse)

Comment: also added a quick and dirty input validator

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
data = []

i=0
max_cycles = 10
while i < max_cycles:

    ingredient = input("Name is your ingredient: ")
    ingredientquantity = int(input("What is the quantity of this ingredient: "))
    ingredientunit = input("What is the unit of your ingredient: ")
    data.append((ingredient, ingredientquantity, ingredientunit))

    print(data)

    i += 1
```

It wil iterate 10 times (max_cycles value) then break, and store all data as tuples inside data list.